# How to use JOIN, CROSS JOIN to combine globalized stored values in SQL into a single table

Tags: sql

We have various tables pertaining to different entities where we would like to globalize the stored values. We do not know how to proceed technically anymore and are open to any form of help, hints or tips.

**Language**

```
ID | Culture | Description |  
---+---------+-------------+
1  | EN      | English     |
2  | FR      | French      | 
3  | ES      | Spanish     |
```

**Job**

```
ID | Description |  
---+-------------+
1  | Doctor      | 
2  | Firefighter |
```

**JobGlobalization**

```
ID | JobID | Description | Culture |
---+-------+-------------+---------+
1  | 1     | Docteur     | FR      |
2  | 1     | Doctora     | ES      |
```

We attempted to use CROSS JOIN to obtain something of the following:

```
ID | Description | Culture |
---+-------------+---------+
1  | Doctor      | EN      |
1  | Doctor      | FR      |
1  | Doctor      | ES      |
2  | Firefighter | ES      |
2  | Firefighter | ES      |
2  | Firefighter | ES      |
```

Query used:

```
SELECT Job.ID, Job.Description, Language.Culture
CROSS JOIN Language
ORDER BY Job.ID
```

We experienced with different joins on the child globalization table in order to correlate the entities together, however the results set kept multiplying itself in the wrong way.

We would like that for every parent entity, whether it has any related child entities, a row is selected for every culture in the Language table. The description column will default to the parent entity in the case where there are no associated records in the child table.

The resulting table should be as follows:

```
ID | Description | Culture |
---+-------------+---------+
1  | Doctor      | EN      |
1  | Docteur     | FR      |
1  | Doctora     | ES      |
2  | Firefighter | EN      |
2  | Firefighter | FR      |
2  | Firefighter | ES      |
```

We had in mind a condition that would select the 'Description' column from the parent table 'Job' if there were no corresponding record for it in the child table.

e.g.

```
IIF(JobGlobalization.Description IS NOT NULL, JobGlobalization.Description, Job.Description)
```

Comment: Your table structure is slightly off, and the `JobGlobalization` table should have entries for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We attempted to use CROSS JOIN to obtain something of the following:

This should produce the result set you describe:

```
SELECT j.ID, j.Description, l.Culture
FROM Job j CROSS JOIN
     Language l
ORDER BY j.ID, l.Culture;
```

You can insert this into `JobGlobalization` (although you might want to truncate it first).  Or you can use `CREATE TABLE AS` (or the equivalent for your database) to create `JobGlobalization` from scratch.

You would then need to update this table with the appropriate values for the culture.

Comment: +1 for pointing in the right direction. We managed to obtain the desired result set by using CASE and WHEN to obtain the appropriate values for the culture that are non-existing in the child table.